# How to debug an event of new line (enter) in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-listener

I'm a newbie to web programming.
I've downloaded a free template of html responsive website & there is a funny behavior I'm trying to debug and find the source/cause

the site has a textbox and a button in a form -- every time I press enter in the textbox the website "reloads"/scrolls to the top.

Textbox has a listener on onkeyup event like this

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="site-block-subscribe">
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="name" type="text" onkeyup="enableBtn()" class="form-control border-secondary text-white bg-transparent" aria-describedby="searchBtn">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="goBtn" disabled>Go</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-5"  id="message"></p>
</form>
```

event.preventDefault(); if the event.keyCode == 13 but it did nothing

```
function enableBtn(){
    name =  document.getElementById("name").value;

    if(name.trim().length > 0) { 
        document.getElementById("goBtn").disabled = false; 
        if(event.keyCode == 13) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("goBtn").click(); // perform the operation as if the GO button was clicked
        }
    } 
    else { 
        document.getElementById("goBtn").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

How can I debug and understand the flow within the files and different functions of the site once an enter is clicked. I don't think the problem I'm facing is in the code shared above - and don't have a clue which file/function creates the problem.

Desired result: on enter or button click, the user will "remain in the same exact page place" and see the returned result in a message.

Important Note: I don't have an IDE and am working with a text editor and Opera browser.

Comment: you have enough rep to know that you should include your code with the question

Comment: Sounds like a form is submitting which is normal behavior.

Comment: In opera, open the inspector and go to "Sources", then "Event Listener Breakpoints" and select the events on which you want the debugger to stop. Or in your code, just add `debugger;` where you want it to stop (inspector must be opened before event fires)

Comment: The question may not have been perfectly clear but: "How can I debug and understand the flow within the files and different functions of the site once an enter is clicked." is somehow interpretable and code-independent so it could have been answered

Comment: @DerekPollard edited the question with code - and as you'll probably see the code has nothing to do with the described problem - so why add code and information that isn't helpful ??

Comment: @epascarello is there a way to stop this normal behavior?  the desired outcome is that on enter like on click of the button the user will remain in the same exact place and see the returned result in a message

Comment: @kukula Mula - it has everything to do with the problem. I see the issue based on your code alone.

Comment: cancel the form submission onsubmit preventDefault or return false

Comment: @DerekPollard - mind sharing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this article helped me solve the problem, hope it will do the same for you all
https://javascript.info/forms-submit

```
<form onsubmit="return false" action="#" method="post" class="site-block-subscribe">
```